What is the probability of rolling the same number at least thrice when throwing four dice?
I know that to get the same number thrice, it must be that
P(A) = 1 x (1/6)^2.
My reason is that 1 represents the first number, which is 100% and (1/6)^2 represents the two following numbers that are similar to the first number. However, I do not know how to account for the condition "at least" and the fact that there would be a fourth die that may possibly be the same number. Can I ask for assistance?

You seem to be a beginner in probability ; a good rule is to auto-check if your reasonning is correct ; for 4 dice, you may obtain (a,a,a,a) (=all 4 dice have same value) or (a,a,a,b), or (a,a,b,b) or (a,a,b,c) or (a,b,c,d) (=4 distinct values) ; you can count how many options for each pattern, and then sum the results. If this sum gives $6^4$ (if sum of probabilitys is 1), good ; if not, there is an error somewhere.

There are two cases.
Case 1: All four numbers are the same. There are 6 possibilities.
Case 2: Three numbers are the same, and the fourth is different.
There are 4 possibilities on which dice is different. There are 6 possibilities on what number appears 3 times. There are 5 remaining possibilities on what number appears once. In total, there are $4\times 6\times 5=120$ possibilities.
Final answer: $\frac{126}{6^4}=\frac{7}{72}$

So the way to go is simply to count the possibilities and divide by 1/6^(the # of dice)? And that the probability is the sum of the two cases? Is there a more general way to approach this like if the number of same dice changes or the number of dice rolled changes?

You divide by 6^(number of dice) not 1/6^(number of dice)

Whoops, sorry. I should've edited that

You asked for a general way
The denominator is obviously going to be $6^4$
For the numerator, you can use the format
$\textbf{[Lay Down Pattern] x [Permute Pattern]}$ to get
$4-0-0-0-0-0:\; \dfrac{4!}{4!}\cdot\dfrac{6!}{5!} = 6$
$3-1-0-0-0-0:\; \dfrac{4!}{3!1!}\cdot\dfrac{6!}{4!} = 120$
totalling to $126$, and yielding $Pr = \dfrac{126}{6^4} = \dfrac 7{72}$
